# How to set a sleep time between cURL multi handles?

Tags: php, curl

I need a time delay between each cURL call so that one process do not start at exactly the same time of another parallel process. In other words, they can run at the same time but not start at the same time.

Is there a way to set some kind of "sleep(2)" on the cURL multi handle?

Comment: Have you thought of using some sort of queue for it?

Comment: @Sukumar Isn't what I'm asking for? See my comment on the Daniel Stenberg answer. Thank you anyway...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multi interface of libcurl process N handles/requests simultaneously. If you need one of the requests to start a bit later, then you can simply add it to the multi interface later!

Comment: +1 That's a good idea, but I keep getting calls at the same time, don't know why. Even setting the next url after a feel seconds. Either way, a change my script and specified the necessary time in the url.